# What is the difference between setX and setTranslationX

Tags: android

What is the difference between setX and setTranslationX on a view? They seem to be the same for me yet they exist both on the android platform.

Thanks

Comment: is setX absolute or is it the left property in relation to its parent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs for `setX()`:

> Sets the visual x position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent
>   to setting the translationX property to be the difference between the
>   x value passed in and the current left property.

Answer (score 1):

`setTranlsationX()` as a relative offset and `setX()` is a fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

`setY()` : Sets the visual y position of this view, in pixels.

`setTranslationY()` : Sets the vertical location of this view relative to its top position.

Answer (score -1):

Here is it in simpler terms:

You have a `View` with `getTop()` as 1000px. `setTranslationY(950)` will set the top to 950. `setTranslationY(2000)` will set the top to 2000.

Similarly, `setTranslationX(950)` will set the left to 950.

**Conclusion:** The translation is about absolute positioning of top or left of a `View`

Comment: Nope, this answer is wrong. setTranslationX() and setTranslationY() will set the location relative to the view's position. Just as it says in the docs.

Comment: @Robert : It is relative, that's right and that's what I have done. I have said, *for instance, if, getTop() returns...then* That is an example